# Чем заменить filter: grayscale для IE?

Tags: css

Чем можно заменить для IE с 9-11 версии?
HTML нельзя менять. Есть modernizr только.

Comment: http://www.majas-lapu-izstrade.lv/cross-browser-grayscale-image-example-using-css3-js/

Comment: Тогда уж лучше [такой подход](http://nikita-sp.com.ua/2015/11/krossbrauzernyiy-grayscale-s-podderzhkoy-internet-explorer-10-11.html) без кучи скриптов, но с фоновыми картинками :)